# KStatusNotifierItem instantiation crashes Qt

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, kde-plasma

I am using Ubuntu Unity 17.04 with Qt 5.11 and I'm having issues with Qt crashing when instantiating KStatusNotifierItem.

Here's my include file:

```
QT += widgets

HEADERS       =    
SOURCES       = main.cpp

# LIBS
LIBS += -lkdeui

# install
target.path = $$[HOME]/KSNITester
INSTALLS += target
```

Here is my source:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "kstatusnotifieritem.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    KStatusNotifierItem * statusItem = new KStatusNotifierItem();
    return a.exec();
}
```

When I run I get a SIGSEGV and the program crashes:

```
Starting /home/anshah/KSNITester/KSNITester...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
The process was ended forcefully.
/home/anshah/KSNITester/KSNITester crashed.
```

Please let me know how I could resolve this issue.

Comment: libkdeui is Qt4 stuff, did you aim to use that?

Comment: I am using Qt5...is it not compatible with Qt5?

Comment: No, use KNotifications framework.

Answer (score 0):

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <KStatusNotifierItem>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    KStatusNotifierItem *sni = new KStatusNotifierItem(&window);
    sni->setCategory(KStatusNotifierItem::ApplicationStatus);
    sni->setIconByName("face-smile");
    sni->setTitle("KStatusNotifierItem Demo");

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

.pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = ksnidemo
QT += widgets dbus KNotifications
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: Which Qt version do you use? Crashes for me on Qt 5.11.

Comment: I am also using Qt 5.11. If it crashes, you are probably still linking in Qt4 material. Check which -dev packages you have installed. If this doesn't help, show us the backtrace of the crash via gdb.

Comment: Do you have instructions to do a clean Qt uninstall and reinstall? I’ve done it a few times with remnants remaining. I’ll retry once I have a clean reinstall.

Comment: Also, just making sure but are you using Ubuntu 17.04 with Unity Desktop?